# ruby gem issue trying to install bundle install

Tags: ruby, oracle, rubygems, bundler, xubuntu

Having issues trying to instal bundle install---I keep getting this error message what am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using activesupport (3.2.13) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.13) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.13) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.13) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.13) 
Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.2) 
Using activeresource (3.2.13) 
Using net-ldap (0.3.1) 
Using adauth (1.2.1) 
Using addressable (2.3.5) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using airbrake (3.1.12) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (3.2.13) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using rails (3.2.13) 
Using best_in_place (2.1.0) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.0.4.2) 
Using cancan (1.6.10) 
Using highline (1.6.19) 
Using net-ssh (2.6.7) 
Using net-scp (1.1.1) 
Using net-sftp (2.1.2) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0) 
Using capistrano (2.12.0) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using xpath (2.0.0) 
Using capybara (2.1.0) 
Using ffi (1.9.0) 
Using childprocess (0.3.9) 
Using chronic (0.9.1) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using composite_primary_keys (5.0.13) 
Using database_cleaner (0.7.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.4) 
Using factory_girl (4.2.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) 
Using sass (3.2.12) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Using font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2) 
Using formatador (0.2.4) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.3) 
Using rb-inotify (0.9.0) 
Using rb-kqueue (0.2.0) 
Using listen (1.2.2) 
Using lumberjack (1.0.4) 
Using method_source (0.8.2) 
Using slop (3.4.6) 
Using pry (0.9.12.2) 
Using guard (1.8.2) 
Using rspec-core (2.14.4) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.14.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.14.2) 
Using rspec (2.14.1) 
Using guard-rspec (3.0.2) 
Using haml (4.0.3) 
Using haml-rails (0.4) 
Using iconv (1.0.3) 
Using jquery-scrollto-rails (1.4.2) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.3) 
Using jquery-ui-sass-rails (4.0.3.0) 
Using kaminari (0.14.1) 
Using launchy (2.3.0) 
Using libv8 (3.11.8.17) 
Using quiet_assets (1.0.2) 
Using ref (1.0.5) 
Using rspec-rails (2.14.0) 
Installing ruby-oci8 (2.1.5) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for load library path... 
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.
  checking ld.so.conf... no
checking for cc... ok
checking for gcc... yes
checking for LP64... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for ruby header... ok
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-instant-client
    --without-instant-client
/home/jsow/.bundler/tmp/23014/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:889:in `get_home': RuntimeError (RuntimeError)
    from /home/jsow/.bundler/tmp/23014/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:705:in `initialize'
    from /home/jsow/.bundler/tmp/23014/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `new'
    from /home/jsow/.bundler/tmp/23014/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5/ext/oci8/oraconf.rb:320:in `get'
    from extconf.rb:18:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------------
Error Message:
  Set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME if Oracle Full Client.
  Append the path of Oracle client libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if Oracle Instant Client.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ruby-oci8` gem needs the Oracle client libraries to compile. According to the error message:

> ```
> Error Message:
>   Set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME if Oracle Full Client.
>   Append the path of Oracle client libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if Oracle Instant Client.
> ```

your `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable is not set, nor can it find the needed libraries in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Make sure that your have either [Oracle Full Client or Oracle Instant Client installed](https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8#installation) and properly set, and try again.